# gnupg for PHP on OSX

Tags: php, macos, gnupg

I'm trying to set up gnupg for use in PHP on my mac.

I have tried following the directions found at the following links:

http://measure9.varkel.net/2013/10/building-gnupg-for-php-5-5-on-osx/
[Install PHP gnupg using PECL on MAC/MAMP 10.8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298725/install-php-gnupg-using-pecl-on-mac-mamp-10-8-4)

What I seem to be running into with both is this message:

checking for gpgme_check_version in -lgpgme... no
configure: error: wrong gpgme lib version or lib not found

I see this when executing the './configure' command.

I have installed gpgme using Homebrew.

I'm a bit stuck as I've tried everything I can come up with and haven't had any luck.

I am running PHP 5.6.7 on OSX 10.10.2 using MAMP Pro.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

EDIT:

My original question was unclear, so I'll try again.

I am trying to install gnupg for use in PHP in my dev environment, which is a macbook using MAMP.

I fist installed gpgme and gnpug using Homebrew, both with no issues.

Then I attempted to install gnupg using pecl via the following command

```
sudo pecl install gnupg
```

And I end up with this error message

```
configure: error: wrong gpgme lib version or lib not found
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/gnupg/configure' failed
```

I have tried editing my path with no success, adding usr/local/include and usr/local/lib, where gpgme.h and libgpgme.a files can be found.  I see no change in the error message.

EDIT 2:

I believe that gpgme is being installed correctly and pecl is able to find it.  I install it using the following command

```
brew install gpgme
```

If I then run the pecl command to install gnupg, I get the error message above.

Now, if I execute the brew command to uninstall gpgme

```
brew uninstall gpgme
```

I see the following error message when trying to install gnupg with pecl

```
configure: error: Please reinstall the gpgme distribution
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/gnupg/configure' failed
```

which seems to indicate that the library is installing and being found, but it's an incorrect version.

I am unable to find any information on what version is required for pecl to install gnupg.

EDIT 3:

Looking at the terminal a little more, I see that it's failing to find a specific function (gpgme_check_version) in the lib file.

```
checking for gpgme_check_version in -lgpgme... no
configure: error: wrong gpgme lib version or lib not found
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/gnupg/configure' failed
```

Comment: Chances are high GnuPG isn't in your `$PATH`. You could be much more specific regarding the commands you ran, and especially what software package you're compiling. Omitting such relevant information or hiding it in some tutorial link (we still don't know what exactly you're doing, anyway) will not increase chances of getting helpful answers. And finally, maybe have a look at the [FAQ]  considerung formatting.

Comment: I edited my original question to be more clear.

Comment: If you install with `homebrew` you leave `homebrew` to do all the configuring and you do NOT run `configure`. You kind of have to choose - either go with `homebrew` and let it do everything, or do everything yourself - but mixing the two is a sure-fire way to get in a mess.

Comment: `gpgme` is not an application but a library, so I misdirected you with `$PATH` (which is for applications, not libraries). There might be some `--with-gpgme=...` option for `configure` or you have to set the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I don't know how exactly PECL and homebrew and MAMP play together here.

Comment: I added some more detail I've uncovered.  If you have any further advice on how to proceed, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what happened, but I believe my installation of autoconf was somehow compromised.

What ended up solving my problem was using brew to uninstall autoconf and gpgme, then using brew to reinstall both packages.