# Installing PHP Extension - Class 'gnupg' not found

Tags: php, gnupg, pecl

I am working on a project that requires using gnupg. I went ahead and installed gnupg on mac using pecl. Next, I added the `extension=gnupg.so` to my php.ini to enable the extension and restarted apache. Now, I am trying to run the following basic code to test:

```
$gpg = new gnupg();
```

And am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'gnupg' not found in ...
```

Also, I noticed the actual directory used to load extensions (shown in phpinfo output) does not contain gnupg.so:

```
/bin/php/php7.0.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/
```

When running `pecl install gnupg`, I get the following output:

```
pecl install gnupg
pecl/gnupg is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.4.0
install failed
```

Comment: You can download the gnupg extension file from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/gnupg) - put it in your directory and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see the *.so file in there, not sure how to link it.

Comment: Oh wait, it's a PECL extension, my brain kinda managed to blend that out x) i found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298725/install-php-gnupg-using-pecl-on-mac-mamp-10-8-4) that might be helping you - it's a shot in the dark for me though, no clearance on that.