# Can't install gnupg on MAC

Tags: php, macos, gnupg

I tried to install the gnupg yet I seem to keep getting the same error. I am using my MAC to install gnup so encode a file.  I'm using PECL to install

```
pecl install gnupg
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh /op/gnupg-1.4.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/opt/gnupg-1.4.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/gnupg-1.4.0/include -I/opt/gnupg-1.4.0/main -I/opt/gnupg-1.4.0 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /opt/gnupg-1.4.0/gnupg.c -o gnupg.lo 

mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/

opt/gnupg-1.4.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/gnupg-1.4.0/include -I/opt/gnupg-1.4.0/main -I/opt/gnupg-1.4.0 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /opt/gnupg-1.4.0/gnupg.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gnupg.o
/opt/gnupg-1.4.0/gnupg.c:21:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found

 #include "php.h"

         ^~~~~~~
```

I have installed the previous packages using the commands:

```
brew install gpg
brew install gpgme
```

I have even tried to download and manually make the extension but I still get the same error.

I had used the instructions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298725/install-php-gnupg-using-pecl-on-mac-mamp-10-8-4).

Does anyone have any ideas about what the issue is?