# Problem Installing gnupg php extension mac m1

Tags: php, homebrew, apple-m1, pecl, gpgme

So i am trying to install gnupg on my mac m1

I found this question and tried to follow this

[Install PHP gnupg using PECL on MAC/MAMP 10.8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298725/install-php-gnupg-using-pecl-on-mac-mamp-10-8-4)

Doesn't seem to work for me, when i run `pecl install gnupg`

[image]

Getting the error `Please reinstall the gpgme distribution`
I have already installed `brew install gpgme`

Please Help

```
% php -version
PHP 8.2.4 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2023 16:10:27) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.2.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: This solved my issue 
https://github.com/php-gnupg/php-gnupg/issues/42

Comment: Are you installing from source? What is your osx version?